# Error: gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found while installing Filezilla

Tags: command-line, apt, updates, ftp

Here I am trying to install Filezilla in ubuntu 16.04. The commands which I use are:

1) `sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu xenial-getdeb apps" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/getdeb.list'`

2) `wget -q -O- http://archive.getdeb.net/getdeb-archive.key | sudo apt-key add -`

3) `sudo apt update && sudo apt install filezilla`

But when I try the second command I am getting an error:

```
gpg: "no valid OpenPGP data found"
```

Can anyone tell me how to overcome this error? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be over complicating the process of installing `filezilla`.

Simply [enable the universe repository](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository)

Then install `filezilla` either via the software center or via the command line with `sudo apt install filezilla`

Source:

testing on Ubuntu 16.04.3